# I am getting this warning "Unused global option(s):”. Can anyone help me?

Tags: fontsize, warnings, resume

This maybe because of using `11pt`, but I need the font size 11pt. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[line,margin,11pt]{res} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond}
\usepackage[%
colorlinks=true,%
urlcolor=blue%
]{hyperref}%

\begin{document}

\name{Name}

\address{1414 XXX} % address 1
\address{E-mail: \href{mailto:aaa@xx.edu}{aaa@xx.edu}} % address 2

\begin{resume}
\section{Education}{My University}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: which documentclass is `res`? If it is one that you've created yourself, it is impossible to replicate the issue. If it is so, use `\begin{filecontents}{res.cls} <class code here> \end{filecontents}` before `\documentclass`

Comment: Besides that, the warning `Unused global option(s):` means that one of the three options you gave to the documentclass is not recognized by the class file you are using, and is therefore ignored.

Comment: It’s the standard res.cls.

Comment: I asked because it is not in my TeXlive distribution. downloaded from ctan. It is 20 years old! Are you sure that moderncv (for instance) isn't a better option?
Besides that, in the cls file the following options are passed to the article class: 11pt an 12pt: `\PassOptionsToClass{11pt,12pt}{article}
`
I guess you can patch it yourself like `\PassOptionsToClass{11pt}{article}
` and remove the option from your documentclass coomand

Comment: @mho `res` is not standard and is not even included in texlive at all as it does not have a suitable licence, so most people do not have it:  it is very old and unsupported.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin I have tried that. But that gives me font size 10pt.

Comment: the font size is 11pt, you can look in the log `size11.clo` is loaded. But apart from this: that I have the class is only chance, and I won't start to be your personal res.cls support. So if you want to insist to use and outdated and buggy class, you will have to read its code and debug it yourself from now on.

Comment: I indeed saw the other question, about the same class, and I agree with @ulrike-fischer. Mho please use  more recent and maintained class. It will save you time and effort

Comment: Since nobody mentioned it yet: a warning is not an error. If you understand the warning and you are ok with the consequences then you can safely ignore the warning. In this case there seem to be no consequences for the output, so there is not really a problem here to be solved.

Comment: Hi Guys. I have solved the problem. So for future reference if anyone ever need can just do the following:                                                                                                               Go to res.cls and comment these two lines                         \PassOptionsToClass{11pt,12pt}{article}
\LoadClassWithOptions{article}
                                                                                                                                            Now put this comment there and remove font size from documentclass. 
\LoadClass[11pt]{article}